# Is it possible to install a Google App Script to a Google Sheet programatically through an API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm developing a webapp in which a user gives consent to my app (using oauth2) to edit/create Google Sheets programatically. This works okay.

In the same way, I want to be able to install (through the API) an App Script (with the user's consent) in that same sheet. Is this possible?

Background: I want this App Script to notify my webapp of any changes to said spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible... The only possibility would be to use a template with an embedded script to create your new spreadsheet but if it already exists then it's too late. You can still add a script manually using the script editor but not using an external script or API.

Comment: OK. Good to know the template-on-create alternative. Thanks